# Programmatically reset/close idle sockets or connections of chrome

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension, connection

I would like to close any idle connections/sockets of chrome browser in order to get a new IP address from my rotating proxies service.

Currently, in surfing the same website, I was getting the same proxy IP address until the socket is closed automatically by chrome or manually by setting in chrome://net-internals/#sockets.

I want to know is there any method to close or reset the sockets programmatically in chrome. It is good to have answers in javascript but others are also welcome.

Comment: Extensions can't do it directly. Extension can run an external utility via nativeMessaging API. That utility could use low-level OS access to close the sockets.

Comment: Does it mean I have to use OS-level command to close the connections? How about if I have multiple chrome browsers running and I just want to reset connections for one browser only each time?

Comment: Your utility will be launched by Chrome directly so you'll be able to determine the parent process id (again by using the OS low-level API), which you'll use to enumerate the sockets of that process and its child Chrome processes.